# How to add a row to a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to add a row in a DataGrid. I want each item to be a string. This is what I've tried:

```
string[] testRow = { "hi", "h2", "h3", "h4" };
myDataGrid.Items.Add(testRow );
```

After doing some research I tried making the items ListBox items and tried this:

```
ListBoxItem user = new ListBoxItem();
user.Content = "hi";

ListBoxItem bname = new ListBoxItem();
bname.Content = "hi2";

ListBoxItem city = new ListBoxItem();
city.Content = "hi3";

ListBoxItem text = new ListBoxItem();
text.Content = "hi4";

ListBoxItem[] row = { user, bname, city, text };

ListBoxItem[] row = { user, bname, city, text };
myDataGrid.Items.Add(row);
```

Then after more research I tried using DataGridRow but no success either...

```
DataGridRow rowt = new DataGridRow();
```

I have 4 data columns. My columns are defined as `DataGridTextColumns`. My rows add successfully, but the results are just blank:
[image]

What the heck am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

From request:

```
                    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="579" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="611" Margin="0,0,-1.286,-1.857" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="User Name"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Business"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="City"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Text"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You also need to show your XAML.Do you get rows in your datagrid but nothing in the columns?

Comment: @slugster added XAML. I added the columns in the GUI and haven't done too much with XAML manually as of yet. The rows show up (I insert 30 rows and 30 rows appear) but they are all blank values. The rows and columns appear as expected...exception as shown in my picture no text is in any of the cells...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/neurik  do you want a datagrid like that?

Comment: @BulutaySaraç Yes that is fine. I'm not too concerned with any formatting at the moment...so that's basically exactly how mine looks. But I cannot get the text to add to the cells......

Comment: @Birdman It's about to bind a List to our datagrid.(most clear way)You need a class for having a clear definition.We will store our datas in an object and we will add them into a List then we will use binding method to show our List in our datagrid.If its fine for you i will add a answer.

Comment: @BulutaySaraç I created a small class to contain the 4 fields I need for the row. Then I tried adding the instantiation of that class. (if that's what you are talking about) That didn't work either.

Comment: @BulutaySaraç If you have an idea that is working, I am happy to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Birdman did you bind your DataGridColumns to your class properties?It works fine for me.

Comment: @BulutaySaraç No...I'm not sure what you mean honestly, so that mean I didn't do it...

Comment: @Birdman i added a solution its a bit advanced but its the most clear way to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class

```
public class Foo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Business { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    //Our List
    public static List<Foo> myList = new List<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo() { UserName = "Username1", Business = "Business1", City = "City1", Text = "Text1" },
        new Foo() { UserName = "Username2", Business = "Business2", City = "City2", Text = "Text2" },
        new Foo() { UserName = "Username3", Business = "Business3", City = "City3", Text = "Text3" },
        new Foo() { UserName = "Username4", Business = "Business4", City = "City4", Text = "Text4" },
        new Foo() { UserName = "Username5", Business = "Business5", City = "City5", Text = "Text5" },
        new Foo() { UserName = "Username6", Business = "Business6", City = "City6", Text = "Text6" }
    };
}
```

**DataGrid** Be carefull while binding.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserName}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="User Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Business}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Business"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding City}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="City"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Text"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**The code for setting itemssource of datagrid.**

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = Foo.myList;
```

ScreenShot
[image]

Comment: Thanks....I tried adding bindings before but I didn't know I need the "Binding" keyword in front of the variable name so it was invalid...thanks for your help it's working perfectly now after I bound to the variable name.

Comment: @Birdman You are welcome.Also when you add your static list a new member.DataGrid automatically refreshes the datagrid source.If it doesn't refresh after adding a new member add the code 'myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();'.

Answer (score 0):

Here i noticed first is DataGrid name is wrong `myDataGrid` and coming to displaying empty row u set the binding to null so. its displaying empty so 
and if u wana bind array u can use binding like this

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="579" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="611" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False">


 <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [0]}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="User Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [0]}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Business"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [0]}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="City"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Text"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>




string[] testRow = { "hi", "h2", "h3", "h4" };
            myDataGrid.Items.Add(testRow);
```

note u can just use `ItemsSource` To bind a entire collection